# How to run mongodb with my username instead of default user mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nodejs

I want to run mongodb service by my defined username and group instead of using mongodb user. How can i change from `mongodb` user to `mydesiredusername`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running `mongodb` as a service, you would need to edit the `upstart` configuration file:

1. Edit `/etc/init/mongodb.conf`.
2. Change the argument `--chuid mongodb` to `--chuid mydesiredusername`. If you need to specify a group, use `--chuid mydesiredusername:mydesiredgroup`.
3. Restart by running `sudo restart mongodb`.

You might also need to change the ownership of your database files (in `/var/lib/mongodb` unless you have changed that as well) and the `/var/log/mongodb` directory and its contents so that `mongodb` can still read and write to its files.

You don't explain why you want to make this change, so maybe you have a good reason. But I would suggest keeping to the default user and finding an alternative solution to the problem you are trying to solve. Services run as their own user for good reasons, not least for security. Changing something like this can cause unexpected problems in the future, make upgrades harder, and is also confusing if other people need to administer your server at a later date.